# Comparing 2 CSV files with compare-object to get outdated software

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to compare 2 csv files to get the outdated software's and put them into another csv file. I have a problem when I try to get the outdated softwares, it just shows all the softwares installed again. This is my script.

```
$CurrentList = Import-csv C:\Users\Administrator\CSVReports\InstalledSoftware.csv | select 
ComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher
$ApprovedList = Import-csv C:\Users\Administrator\ApprovedSoftware\ApprovedSoftwareList.csv | select 
DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher
$ApprovedList = $ApprovedList | select ComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher

$Outdated = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CurrentList -DifferenceObject $ApprovedList -Property 
DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher -PassThru | Where Sideindicator -eq '<='

$Outdated = $Outdated | Foreach {
$Item = $_
$ApprovedVersion = $ApprovedList | Where {$_.DisplayName -eq $Item.DisplayName -and $_.Publisher -eq 
$Item.Publisher } | Select -ExpandProperty DisplayVersion -First 1
[PSCustomObject]@{
    ComputerName = $_.ComputerName
    DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
    CurrentVersion = $_.DisplayVersion
    ApprovedVersion = $ApprovedVersion
    Publisher = $_.Publisher

  }
}

$Outdated | export-csv OutdatedSoftware.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My CSV files look like this

InstalledSoftware.csv

```
ComputerName     DisplayName     DisplayVersion     Publisher

Win2008R2        Google Chrome   86.0.4280.88       Google LLC
Win2008R2        VmWare Tools    10.3.5.10430147    VMWare, LLC
Win2012R2        Google Chrome   86.0.4280.88       Google LLC
Win2012R2        VmWare Tools    10.3.5.10430147    VMWare, LLC
Win2016          Google Chrome   86.0.4280.88       Google LLC
Win2016          VmWare Tools    10.3.5.10430147    VMWare, LLC
```

ApprovedList.csv

```
DisplayName     DisplayVersion     Publisher

Google Chrome   87.0.4280.88       Google LLC
VmWare Tools    10.3.5.10430147    VMWare, LLC
```

Only chrome should be in the OutDatedSoftware csv as only the chrome version is different but I get all the softwares. I also want to know which server the software is on. Appreciate the help.

Comment: You have a typo in your approved select statement - DisplayVerision

Comment: I've voted to close your question as a mere typo. If @DougMaurer's comment doesn't fix the problem please leave a comment and I'll retract my vote.

Comment: Yea, sorry its a typo, it still doesnt fix the problem

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It would be much easier to help if we could just copy-paste the input data and play around with it.

Comment: Sorry, im still quite new. Ive added example lines of the csv files

Answer (score 0):

I'm having weird results with Publisher. This should do the trick, however

```
$CurrentList = Import-csv C:\Users\Administrator\CSVReports\InstalledSoftware.csv
$ApprovedList = Import-csv C:\Users\Administrator\ApprovedSoftware\ApprovedSoftwareList.csv

$Outdated = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CurrentList -DifferenceObject $ApprovedList -Property DisplayName, DisplayVersion -PassThru | Where-Object Sideindicator -eq '<='

$Outdated = foreach($oldversion in $Outdated)
{
    $oldversion.DisplayName
    $ApprovedList | Where {$_.DisplayName -eq $oldversion.DisplayName} | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName    = $oldversion.ComputerName
            DisplayName     = $oldversion.DisplayName
            CurrentVersion  = $oldversion.DisplayVersion
            ApprovedVersion = $_.DisplayVersion
            Publisher       = $oldversion.Publisher
        }
    }
}

$Outdated | Export-Csv OutdatedSoftware.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This still shows softwares with same CurrentVersion and ApprovedVersion

Comment: Not in my tests

Comment: Hmm it seems to only work for the first ComputerName. The ones after doesnt get filtered

Answer (score 0):

That new code work fine ...
Except that if your csv are tab delimited, you will need to specify it when importing the csv.

Add

```
`-Delimiter "`t"`
```

to your 2 `Import-csv` statements.

```
Import-csv C:\Users\Administrator\CSVReports\InstalledSoftware.csv | select ComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher
Import-csv C:\Users\Administrator\ApprovedSoftware\ApprovedSoftwareList.csv  -Delimiter "`t" | select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher
```

Assuming your csv are tab-delimited properly, it should work.
If it still doesn't afterward, try the Import statement in the console alone to see what is actually imported before going further.

When testing from your example, SO did not preserve the tab delimiter so it didn't produce the proper results at first.

edit:

Based on your comment, your csv appear to be improperly formatted.
Not specifying the tab delimited for a tab delimited csv will import the csv as a 1 column object.

**Incorrect** -

While pretty, all the columns are linked together, meaning you actually have only one column. This can be validated by trying to access any of the column. They will all be blanks.

The only column being imported in this case is called `ComputerName     DisplayName     DisplayVersion     Publisher`
[image]

**Correct**

Notice there is no dashes  in-between each column. The csv have definitely 4 columns.
[image]

Comment: When i add the `-Delimiter "`t"`, The output for my $CurrentList and $ApprovedList is empty, without it, it shows the correct entries

Comment: @Keith Then your csv is not properly delimited. If you do `Import-Csv` without specifying the delimiter, it get imported as a comma separated delimiter, which means you are importing one column called `ComputerName      DisplayName     DisplayVersion     Publisher` and not 4. This should be clearly visible in the console by the fact these column are interlinked with dashes. Try to select any of the individual property (eg: `$CurrentCsv | Select ComputerName` and they should be all empty. You need to use a proper tab-delimited CSV file.

Comment: Also, if what you pasted in your question is the CSV, this is definitely wrong. A tab delimited csv wouldn't be aligned like that.

Comment: I did `$CurrentCsv | Select ComputerName` and i got the correct output with the different computer names. It works but i get softwares with the same approved versions and current versions